# Загрузка скриптов при скроле

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вписать в код ниже несколько скриптов, что бы они подгружались при скроле?

Код:

```
<script>
var fired = false;
 
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (fired === false) {
        fired = true;
        
        setTimeout(() => {
                    
???  
        }, 1000)
    }
});
</script>
```

Скрипты:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://wstep4.biz/?pu=grstanjtgu5ha3ddf4ztgobr" async></script>
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script src="https://qdb6gd3nth.ru/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, `addEventListener('scroll')` сработает не только при скролле, но и сразу после перезагрузки страницы, если ту перезагрузили сперва хоть сколь-нибудь прокрутив.

Браузеры при перезагрузке страницы открывают её на том же месте где остановились, а это вызывает событие `scroll`.

```
let tired = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (tired) return;
  tired = true;

  let objUrls = {
    1: '#url1',
    2: '#url2',
    3: '#url3',
  };

  setTimeout(() => {
    genHtmlFromObject(objUrls);
    alert('Скрипты добавлены');
  }, 3000);

  function genHtmlFromObject(obj) {
    for (const scriptUrl in obj) {
      const url = obj[scriptUrl];

      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = url;
      document.body.append(script);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<script>alert(5)</script>');` — простейший пример, не срабатывает. Нужно создавать скрипт через `createElement('script')` + `appendChild()`